# Trim string after 5 of the same chars are found

Tags: regex, python-2.7, substring, trim

Say I have a the string `AAAGCTTACGAAAAAAACGTA` and I would like to remove anything after and including the occurrence of 4 `A`s, regardless of where it occurs in the string. So for this example we are left with `AAAGCTTACG` after trimming. What would be a fast and efficient way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> s = "AAAGCTTACGAAAAAAACGTA"
>>> s.split("AAAA", 1)[0]
'AAAGCTTACG'
```

Comment: Very nice. I'm not a Python specialist, but I have a feeling that this might be faster than the regex approach.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a greedy match and replace with nothing.

```
import re
new_string = re.sub(r'AAAA.*', '', original_string)
```

Alternatively, `AAAA` can also be expressed as `A{4}` if you find it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just `find` those `AAAA` if any, and slice:

```
>>> s = "AAAGCTTACGAAAAAAACGTA"
>>> s[:s.find("AAAA")]
'AAAGCTTACG'
```

However, this way you should first check whether the string contains `AAAA`, otherwise it will slice away the last character.